# Validar Campos e Fazer Formulário Enviar

Tags: javascript

Nesse script abaixo eu valido os campos se as senha forem iguais 
eu não estou sabendo como fazer o form só funcionar se as senha forem iguais

```
<script>
function validarSenha() {
  NovaSenha = document.FormSenha.Password.value
  CNovaSenha = document.FormSenha.CNovaSenha.value

  if (NovaSenha == CNovaSenha) {
    $("#status2").slideDown();
    $("#status2").html(" Senha OK"); // abre minha div
    // regra para fazero o formulario enviar
    setTimeout(function() { // fecha minha div
      $("#status2").remove();
    }, 5000);
  } else {
    $("#status").slideDown();
    $("#status").html(" A Segunda senha não confere");
    // regra para não fazer o formulario enviar                     
    setTimeout(function() { // 
      $("#status").remove();
    }, 5000);
  }
} 
</script>
```

```html
<?
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
$datalog = date('Y-m-d');
$horalog = date('H:i:s');
$ip = file_get_contents('https://api.ipify.org'); // Pega o ip WAN
   echo $id = $_SESSION["id_user"];

    $acao = $_REQUEST["ac"];
    $id_user = $_REQUEST["err"];
    $acao2 = $_REQUEST["ac2"];
    
if ($acao == 'troc'){
require_once("sis/gerenciador/assets/lconfig.php");     
       
       
                     
          if (isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) { 
        $id_user = $_REQUEST["err"];
        $senha_a = md5(trim($_REQUEST["senha_antiga"])); 



$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id_user='$id_user' AND senha_n = '$senha_a' "); 
    $dados = mysql_fetch_array($sql); 


if(mysql_num_rows($sql) <= 0){

$alert = '<div style=" 
                        color: white; 
                        height: 50px; 
                        border-style: solid;
                        background-color: red;padding-left: 20px; padding-top: 8px; border-radius: 10px; font-size: 14px;"> 
Senha Antiga não confere
</div>
';

$sql = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO log 
(id_transfer,id_user,acao,usuario,data,ip)VALUES
('$id_transfer1','$id_user','Senha Tentativa de Trocar Senha','$login','$datalog.$horalog','$ip')", $conecta) or die( mysql_error());

    
}else{

$alert = '<div style=" 
                        color: white; 
                        height: 50px; 
                        border-style: solid;
                        background-color: green;padding-left: 20px; padding-top: 8px; border-radius: 10px; font-size: 14px;"> 
Senha Alterada com Sucesso
</div>
';


     $Password = md5(trim($_REQUEST["Password"])); 

$consulta = "UPDATE usuarios SET senha_n = '$Password',acesso = '0' 
WHERE id_user = '$id_user'";
$resultado = mysql_query($consulta) or die( mysql_error());

    
$sql = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO log 
(id_transfer,id_user,acao,usuario,data,ip)VALUES
('$id_transfer1','$id_user','$id_user Alterou sua Senha','$login','$datalog.$horalog','$ip')", $conecta) or die( mysql_error());
    

}}




?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="fluid top-full sticky-top sidebar sidebar-full">

 

<head>
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
<meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">
    <title>Go Transfer - Sistema de Gest&atilde;o para empresas de Transporte Executivo e Receptivo</title> <meta name="Transfer-Online" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <meta name="author" content="transfer-online.net">   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/images/favicon.png" type="image/png">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
 <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
 <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="sis/gerenciador/assets/css/admin/module.admin.page.login.min.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-aUGj/X2zp5rLCbBxumKTCw2Z50WgIr1vs/PFN4praOTvYXWlVyh2UtNUU0KAUhAX" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-K1qjQ+NcF2TYO/eI3M6v8EiNYZfA95pQumfvcVrTHtwQVDG+aHRqLi/ETn2uB+1JqwYqVG3LIvdm9lj6imS/pQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://github.com/makeusabrew/bootbox/releases/download/v4.4.0/bootbox.min.js"></script>

<!----------------------------comparando senha---------------------------------------->
<script>
function validarSenha() {
  NovaSenha = document.getElementById("Password").value;
  CNovaSenha = document.getElementById("CNovaSenha").value;

  if (NovaSenha != CNovaSenha) {
    $("#status2").slideDown();
    $("#status2").html("A Segunda senha não confere");
    setTimeout(function() { $("#status2").remove(); }, 5000);
    return false;
  }

  return true;
} 
</script>

<!----------------------------------meter-------------------------------------------------------------->
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.alert = function(){};
        var defaultCSS = document.getElementById('bootstrap-css');
        function changeCSS(css){
            if(css) $('head > link').filter(':first').replaceWith('<link rel="stylesheet" href="'+ css +'" type="text/css" />'); 
            else $('head > link').filter(':first').replaceWith(defaultCSS); 
        }
        $( document ).ready(function() {
          var iframe_height = parseInt($('html').height()); 
          window.parent.postMessage( iframe_height, 'http://bootsnipp.com');
        });
    </script>
<script language="javascript" src="sis/gerenciador/assets/js/meter/meter.js"></script>
<!----------------------------------meter-------------------------------------------------------------->

</head>
<body class="login ">
<?echo $alert?>
<div id="status" style="display: none;  
                        color: white; 
                        height: 50px; 
                        border-style: solid;
                        background-color: red;padding-left: 20px; padding-top: 8px; border-radius: 10px; font-size: 14px;"> 

</div>

<div id="status2" style="display: none;  
                        color: white; 
                        height: 50px; 
                        border-style: solid;
                        background-color: green;padding-left: 20px; padding-top: 8px; border-radius: 10px; font-size: 14px;"> 

</div>


<br /><br />
<h2 style="text-align: center;"> Alterar Senha</h2>
<div id="login">
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
 <div class="wrapper"><br />
 <div class="widget widget-heading-simple widget-body-gray">
 <div class="widget-body">
 <form method="POST" onsubmit="validarSenha() class="form" id="FormSenha" name="FormSenha" action="troca.php" >
            
                        <input type="hidden" name="ac"  value="troc"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="err"  value="<?echo $id_user?>"/>
      <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="login"    value="<?echo $login?>"/> 
                        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="login"  value=""/> 
      <label>Senha Antiga:</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control"  maxlength="12" size="12"  name="senha_antiga" placeholder="Senha" />
                        <label>Nova Senha:</label>
      <input class="form-control" required=""  id="Password" name="Password" data-val="true" data-val-length="Minimo 6 caracteres." data-val-length-max="100" data-val-length-min="6" data-val-required="password is required" placeholder="min 6 caracteres" maxlength="12" rows="12" type="password" />
                        <div id="pw-val-container">
                          <div id="pw-val-progress">
                                        <div id="pw-val-verdict"></div>
                                        <div id="pw-val-errors"></div>
                          </div>
                        
                        <label>Repita a Senha:</label>
                        <input type="password" required="" class="form-control"  maxlength="12" size="12" id="CNovaSenha" onblur="validarSenha()"  name="senha2" placeholder="Repita" />
    
      <a class="password" href="">Esqueceu sua senha?</a>
                     <div class="separator bottom clearfix"></div>
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8">
      <button  class="btn btn-block btn-inverse" onblur="validarSenha()" name="submit" type="submit">Alterar</button></div>
      <div class="col-md-4 center"><button  class="btn btn-block" style="background-color: #8080FF; color: white;" onblur="validarSenha()" name="submit" type="submit">Logar</button></div>
 </div>
 </form></div></div></div></div>
        <div class="col-md-4">      
                    
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2"></div></div>
    </div></div>
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12"<br /><h3 style="text-align: center;"><strong> Sistema de Gest&atilde;o Integrada    </strong></h3>
    <h6 style="text-align: center;">Todos os direitos reservados a Mpitech</h6>
    <div class="widget-body" style="text-align: right;">
 </p>
    </div></div></div></div>
 
<?}?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Algo que pode fazer, se já não está fazendo isso, é chamar a função `validarSenha` no evento `onsubmit` do formulário:

```
<form ... onsubmit="validarSenha()">
```

Desta forma, quando o usuário pressionar o botão de enviar, será chamada a função, validando as senhas. O interessante é que se essa função retornar `true`, a requisição é propagada naturalmente, conforme você definiu no `action` do formulário. Mas se retornar `false`, a requisição é cancelada. Neste caso, é melhor você apenas verificar quando as senhas não são iguais, como abaixo:

```
function validarSenha() {
  var NovaSenha = document.getElementById("Password").value;
  var CNovaSenha = document.getElementById("CNovaSenha").value;

  if (NovaSenha != CNovaSenha) {
    $("#status2").slideDown();
    $("#status2").html("A Segunda senha não confere");
    setTimeout(function() { $("#status2").remove(); }, 5000);
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

Ou seja, se a senha for diferente, aparece a mensagem de erro e retorna `false`, cancelando a requisição do formulário. Caso contrário, retorna `true`, permitindo que o formulário seja enviado.

Comment: tentei aqui mais ainda esta executando o <form mesmo com es senha diferentes

Comment: Tem como postar o código? Acredito que possa editar a pergunta, adicionando o novo código ao final.

Comment: Coloquei o codigo completo

Comment: Console apresenta algum erro?

Comment: aqui nenhum....

Comment: Resolvi colocando   $("#FormSenha").submit(function(){
    return false; 
    });

Comment: mais ele só checa uma vez , preciso dar um reload para refazer a checagem voce saberia o porque disso?

Answer (score 0):

Cheguei a uma solução que deu certo

```
$("#FormSenha").submit(function(){
return false; 
});
```

```js
function validarSenha() {
  NovaSenha = document.FormSenha.Password.value
  CNovaSenha = document.FormSenha.CNovaSenha.value

  if (NovaSenha == CNovaSenha) {
    $("#status2").slideDown();
    $("#status2").html(" Senha OK"); // abre minha div
    $("#FormSenha").submit(function(){
    return true; 
    });  
    setTimeout(function() { // fecha minha div
      $("#status2").remove();
    }, 5000);
    return true
  } else {
    $("#status").slideDown();
    $("#status").html(" A Segunda senha não confere");
    // regra para não fazer o formulario enviar                     
    $("#FormSenha").submit(function(){
    return false; 
    });
    setTimeout(function() { // 
      $("#status").remove();
    }, 5000);
    return false
  }
}
```