# Script de Comparação de senhas Só faz a checagem uma só vez

Tags: javascript

Meu script só funciona uma vez, para faze-lo funcionar tenho que dar um relaod na pagina.

Esse script abaixo ele checa se a senhas são diferentes.

Quando eu coloco uma senha correta no 1º campo e de proposito uma errada no segundo, ele vai me retornar que a senhas não conferem. o probela e quando eu coloco de novo a senha correta ele não realiza mais o check só executa uma vez a função como posso resolver isso

```js
function validarSenha() {
  NovaSenha = document.FormSenha.Password.value
  CNovaSenha = document.FormSenha.CNovaSenha.value

  if (NovaSenha == CNovaSenha) {
    $("#status2").slideDown();
    $("#status2").html(" Senha OK"); // abre minha div
    $("#FormSenha").submit(function(){
    return true; 
    });  
    setTimeout(function() { // fecha minha div
      $("#status2").remove();
    }, 5000);
    return true
  } else {
    $("#status").slideDown();
    $("#status").html(" A Segunda senha não confere");
    // regra para não fazer o formulario enviar                     
    $("#FormSenha").submit(function(){
    return false; 
    });
    setTimeout(function() { // 
      $("#status").remove();
    }, 5000);
    return false
  }
} 

//medidor de Senha forte
        window.alert = function(){};
        var defaultCSS = document.getElementById('bootstrap-css');
        function changeCSS(css){
            if(css) $('head > link').filter(':first').replaceWith('<link rel="stylesheet" href="'+ css +'" type="text/css" />'); 
            else $('head > link').filter(':first').replaceWith(defaultCSS); 
        }
        $( document ).ready(function() {
          var iframe_height = parseInt($('html').height()); 
          window.parent.postMessage( iframe_height, 'http://bootsnipp.com');
        });
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    
<body class="login ">
<?echo $alert?>
<div id="status" style="display: none;  
                        color: white; 
                        height: 50px; 
                        border-style: solid;
                        background-color: red;padding-left: 20px; padding-top: 8px; border-radius: 10px; font-size: 14px;"> 

</div>

<div id="status2" style="display: none;  
                        color: white; 
                        height: 50px; 
                        border-style: solid;
                        background-color: green;padding-left: 20px; padding-top: 8px; border-radius: 10px; font-size: 14px;"> 

</div>


<br /><br />
<h2 style="text-align: center;"> Alterar Senha</h2>
<div id="login">
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
 <div class="wrapper"><br />
 <div class="widget widget-heading-simple widget-body-gray">
 <div class="widget-body">
 <form method="POST"  class="form" id="FormSenha" name="FormSenha" action="troca.php" >
            
                        <input type="hidden" name="ac"  value="troc"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="err"  value="<?echo $id_user?>"/>
      <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="login"    value="<?echo $login?>"/> 
                        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="login"  value=""/> 
      <label>Senha Antiga:</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control"  maxlength="12" size="12"  name="senha_antiga" placeholder="Senha" />
                        <label>Nova Senha:</label>
      <input class="form-control" required=""  id="Password" name="Password" data-val="true" data-val-length="Minimo 6 caracteres." data-val-length-max="100" data-val-length-min="6" data-val-required="password is required" placeholder="min 6 caracteres" maxlength="12" rows="12" type="password" />
                        <div id="pw-val-container">
                          <div id="pw-val-progress">
                                        <div id="pw-val-verdict"></div>
                                        <div id="pw-val-errors"></div>
                          </div>
                        
                        <label>Repita a Senha:</label>
                        <input type="password" required=""  class="form-control"  maxlength="12" size="12" id="CNovaSenha" onblur="validarSenha()"  name="senha2" placeholder="Repita" />
    
      <a class="password" href="">Esqueceu sua senha?</a>
                     <div class="separator bottom clearfix"></div>
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8">
      <button  class="btn btn-block btn-inverse" onclick="validarSenha()"  name="submit" type="submit">Alterar</button></div>
      <div class="col-md-4 center"><button  class="btn btn-block" style="background-color: #8080FF; color: white;" onblur="validarSenha()" name="submit" type="submit">Logar</button></div>
 </div>
 </form></div></div></div></div>
        <div class="col-md-4">      
                    
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2"></div></div>
    </div></div>
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Validar Campos e Fazer Formulário Enviar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/185261/validar-campos-e-fazer-formul%c3%a1rio-enviar)

Answer (score 0):

uma das **possíveis abordagens** *(não quero dizer que seja a única)*, será **definir um timer**, digamos ***10000 ms***, e **triggar a função a partir daí**, tal como descrito no **código de exemplo abaixo**

```
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

function myTimer() {
    var d = new Date();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d.toLocaleTimeString();
}
```

presente em https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp